What is the most fuel-efficient flight profile for a small plane?
If you take a short one hour flight in an A320, the flight will usually climb to around 25 - 30,000ft and then descend into its destination. The actual cruise at 30,000 will often only be a matter of minutes. The reason for this, I understand is it's the most economic (fuel sparing) flight path.
What is the most economical vertical flight path to take when flying a small plane (say a 152 or ultralight) for a flight duration of around an hour?
I recently tried the "A320" approach by climbing to 10,000ft (the flight ceiling) and then switching to idle. But since small planes often don't have a great glide ratio, including the one I used (C42), I believe that flight was less economical than usual, it took a very long time to get up there at a fairly high power setting.

Note: airlines uses (and adapt) a factor to calculate that, which may include too much parameters. Possibly you should restrict: more fuel efficient way, right? (so without taking into account time, wages, etc.)

Similar: How do I determine the best altitude to fly for fuel economy? and for commercial airliner insight: How do pilots decide what their cruising altitude will be?

If you're using Skydemon, it will calculate the best altitude for you for a given flight. You of course need to have it configured with your fuel burn and it needs up to date weather.

Flight ceiling is, pretty much by definition, maximum but not optimal. For example, A320 has a service ceiling (based on a quick search) of ~ 40,000 feet. If the typical 1-hour cruise only for a little bit flight hits 30,000, and in fact most longer flights probably somewhere between 30k and 35k, the logical thing for a small place with a ceiling of 10k would be optimum somewhere below that - e.g., perhaps 5k or 7k or similar.

The fuel burn on a jet is so awful at low altitude it's worth it to get as high as possible as soon as possible even for a short leg like that. On a propeller lightplane there's a difference but it's a lot more subtle. In any case, if you're paying for the airplane, wet, on a Hobbs meter, your economic incentive is to get there as soon as you possibly can and fuel burn doesn't come into it, so the most efficient cost wise for the renter pilot is pedal to the metal. If it's a dry rental, different story.

What John said, just be careful if its wet rental with a tacho instead of a hobbs

@JohnK I tried "pedal to the metal" but cruising with full right rudder really made my cruise performance awful...

It depends on a lot of factors so it's hard to make generalizations. But for such a short flight, in most GA aircraft the minimum fuel burn profile is almost definitely flying the minimum legal altitude. Or the altitude with the most favorable winds, if there is a significant difference.
Here is a plot of the range profile of a Cessna 152 with standard tanks:

You can see that, at minimum cruise power, the range is maximum if flying at sea level and only decreases with higher altitude.
On the other hand, here is the same plot for a Cessna 152 with the optional extended range tanks:

You can see a modest increase in range up to 4000 feet and a decrease afterwards. The much longer flight allows for the modest efficiency gain of flying higher to make up for the extra fuel burned in the climb.
This is about a nine hour flight, though. It takes basically the whole 9 hours of fuel savings in cruise to make up for the fuel burned in the climb.
Note that these charts are based on a maximum performance climb. A somewhat faster airspeed climb could possibly give some fuel savings. But most POHs do not contain the information necessary to analyze fuel burn with arbitrary climb speeds.
This is based just off of fuel economy. Keep in mind that many maintenance costs depend on the number of hours spent in flight. Saving a few dollars on fuel isn't very helpful if it costs more than that in additional maintenance costs.

Few aircraft in the class of the 152 have a high enough service ceiling for reduced fuel burn at altitude to matter much, plus unless you have oxygen you're limited to 12,000 feet as a general rule.
Likely the biggest factor to save fuel with these aircraft is to avoid high throttle once you're clear of the airport and high enough to reduce throttle.  You'll burn a lot less per mile traveled at 70% than you would at 100% throttle, and reducing to 50% will save even more -- and because drag goes as the square of speed, flying, say, 20% slower saves more than 20% on fuel burn, so your overall "fuel mileage" is better when you throttle back.
Second is to ensure you're running the mixture as lean as EGT and head temperature (depending on available instruments) will allow.  Back in WWII, correct mixture management added more than 20% to the range of a P-38.

It took me a while to follow the logic of "the loss of speed is much less than the decrease in fuel burn" - is a clearer formulation of that sentence possible?  Perhaps just some emphasis that it's lower fuel per distance as well as per time.

Of course, the first person to use oxygen to set an altitude record did it by the simple expedient of shoving an oxygen tank under the seat and holding the end of the tube between his teeth... But eventually you'll also need extra air for the engine, so a supercharger may be in order...

Zeiss Ikon covers a lot of the points about operation of the physical aircraft but I think one of the most critical choices in light aircraft efficiency can be:
Winds Aloft
Your most economical flight path can be the one that takes the greatest advantage of winds aloft and/or avoids large headwinds. With modern flight planning apps like Foreflight you can generally see these options in realtime if you have programed your fuel burns in.
If you flying VFR you can take advantage (within safe altitudes) of choosing your cruse altitude to optimize tail winds and avoid head winds.
For example lets say I wanted to fly from KDXR to KDDH right now, I can climb up to 11,000 feet  where Im nice and high and close to my service ceiling but if i stay a bit lower at 5000 and take advantage of the tailwind Ill burn 2.9 less gallons of fuel and get there at the same time. Its worth noting this is my 55% lean mixture profile which is the most efficient for this aircraft. If time is of no factor to you this will generally always yield the lowest burns. The spreads are comparable at my other throttle positions with higher burns throughout.

(Source: Own Image)

Light aircrafts have special fuel consumption characteristics because of their design, dimensions, power plant and other factors. Small aircraft especially those used for private uses should have details on the performance factors among them being glide ratio and the climb rate. The recommended operating environment is at a height of 3,000 – 5,000 feet, and the most preferable climb and descent gradient should be a moderate gradient. More to do’s include the flight planning, management of the fuel and referring to the Pilot’s Operating Handbook (POH) for better performance.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Although this answer is elegantly phrased, it doesn't actually answer the question.
